# SharePoint 2013 life cycle end

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Can anyone please provide info on when Microsoft will be going to end support for SharePoint server 2013.

I have been trying to find out this info from Microsoft blogs and other internet sources with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Microsoft Lifecycle Policy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/lifecycle) gives you consistent and predictable guidelines for the availability of support throughout the life of a product.

**Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Service Pack 1:**

- Lifecycle Start Date: **2014-02-25**
- Mainstream Support End Date: **2018-04-10**
- Extended Support End Date: **2023-04-11**

Answer (score 4):

**First,** to check the Product Lifecycle for Microsoft products check

## [Product lifecycle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Microsoft%20SharePoint%20Server%202013)

**Second,** For SharePoint 2013 there is no a clear  `Mainstream or Extended Support End Date` yet. Meanwhile, For SP 2013 SP 1

- The `Mainstream support End date` will end at **4/10/2018**
- The `Extended support End date` will end at **4/11/2023**

[image]